# How to style and structure internal <div> to maintain parent <div> size on mobile without using px for dimensions

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am making a video UI with different layers that show/hide using JQuery. Currently, the overlays are matching the default video player size regardless of screen sizing on desktop. Sadly on mobile (iPhone) the overlays only have enough height to fit the content rather than full video player height.

I've tried different nesting of divs and many combinations and classes for parent and child divs CSS including:
position: relative/absolute
display: table/table-cell/block etc
Using px sizes for parent div helped but it gives less control of video player size when resizing screens/browser. Allowing it to auto-size for the screen is more user-friendly.

```css
.video-box {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay1,
.overlay2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.content {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-box">
  <video><source src="video.mp4"></video>

  <div class="overlay1">
    <div class="content">
      <h3>You are about to watch a video</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="overlay2">
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Video is over</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to have each layer match the exact size and cover the video player with the text content centered vertically and horizontally. The code I'm using makes it work on desktop (including chrome inspect mobile resizing) but not on actual mobile device. The overlay only sizes horizontally to fit the text content and not the full video player height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than having a second div, the `.content`, you can use [css-flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to get the content to be in the middle. Please try the below code.

```css
.video-box {
  position: relative;
}

video {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="video-box">
  <video><source src="https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4"></video>

  <div class="overlay">
    <h3>video is over</h3>
    <p>what to do next</p>
  </div>

  <div class="overlay">
    <h3>Video is over</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That solves my alignment and overlay sizing issues but text elements continue on the same line even in p tags or h tags instead of starting on a new line. Is there something in the flex formatting that causes this? I have placed my full css for the div below for any possible conflicts

Comment: what do you mean by new line? there will be only one `h` or `p` based on your condition of video start and end

Comment: example writing: <h3>video is over</h3><p>what to do next</p> all runs on the same line instead of p starting new line. There will be more complex content than this example including buttons etc but everything in the div runs consecutively. How do I prevent this?

Comment: just use `flex-direction: column;`, have edited the code, thanks

Comment: Thanks for adding flex-direction line it has fixed the formatting issue

Comment: @RichardR perfect